# Is using sagaMiddleware.run inside a callback an okay pattern

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, redux-saga

I am using firebase to handle my login auth. I use the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(callback)` method to listen for auth changes and then in the callback dispatch actions as required. In order to get this working with redux-saga I have the following setup. It works, but I want to know if using `sagaMiddleware.run()` inside a helper function like this is okay.

LoginSaga.js

```
const returnAuthData = (handleLogin) => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authData => sagaMiddleware.run(handleLogin, authData))
}

function* handleLogin(authData) {
  const state = select()
  if (authData) {
    yield put(loginUser(authData))
  } else {
    if (state.auth && state.auth.currently !== ANONYMOUS) {
      yield put(logOutUser())
    }
  }
}

export function* listeningForAuth() {
  returnAuthData(handleLogin)
}
```

main.js

```
...    
sagaMiddleware.run(listeningForAuth)
...
```

Comment: Why can't you dispatch an action in the callback?

Comment: That would be ideal but where would dispatch come from in this situation?

Comment: In the `onAuthStateChanged` callback

Comment: Sorry not sure I get it. There is nowhere the redux store is going to pass in the dispatch method for me to use.

Comment: Why not? Have a component towards the top `<Firebase>`, which has has access to the store via context, and in the `componentWillMount` method call your `onAuthChanged` method